# Trouble encoding WAV to FLAC in web application using libflac.js

Tags: node.js, audio, encoding, flac

I need to **encode** a `WAV` file for my web application. I have not yet decided, if the encoding/decoding process will be running in the backend or frontend. **However**, my main problem right now is **actually implementing** the encoding (and decoding) of a `WAV` file to `FLAC` format. The goal here is to significantly reduce the file size before later storing it in *Firebase Storage* for archive.

**Sadly**, there aren't many **resources** to learn from for beginners, nor options to choose from when it comes to `npm` `FLAC` **packages** other than [libflac.js](https://github.com/mmig/libflac.js/blob/master/README.md). **Despite following the documentation** I can't get the code to work.

---

## What I've tried so far...

My approach was to get the data from a Javascript `File` object and **encode** it using code like in their [GitHub](https://github.com/mmig/libflac.js/blob/master/tools/test/unit/utils-enc.ts) `tools` **folder**, since the demo/tutorial in the docs didn't work for me either.

## Problem:

1. Code stuck at `flac.FLAC__stream_encoder_process_interleaved` inside the `else` block for some reason.
2. `fdata` is still `[]` after `flac.init_encoder_stream`

`flacEncoder.ts`:

```js
import Flac, { StreamMetadata, CompressionLevel } from 'libflacjs/dist/libflac'; 

// my api endpoint calls this function and passes the received WAV file to be encoded to FLAC
export async function encodeFLAC(file: File) {
    const arrBuf = await file.arrayBuffer()
    const buf = Buffer.from(arrBuf)
    const bytes = new Int32Array(buf, buf.byteOffset, buf.byteLength / 4)

    if (!Flac.isReady()) {
        Flac.on('ready', (evt: Flac.ReadyEvent) => {
            console.log("Flac is ready now: ", evt.target)
            encode(Flac, 44100, 2, 32, 4, bytes, exportCallback, true)
        })
    } else {
        encode(Flac, 44100, 2, 32, 4, bytes, exportCallback, true)
    }
}

function encode(flac: any, sampleRate: number, channels: number, bps: number, compressionLevel: CompressionLevel, data: Int32Array, cb: (data: Uint8Array[], metadata: StreamMetadata) => void, encodeInterleaved: boolean): void {
    const enc = flac.create_libflac_encoder(sampleRate, channels, bps, compressionLevel, 0, true);
    const fdata: Uint8Array[] = [];
    let metadata: StreamMetadata | null = null;

    flac.init_encoder_stream(enc, (data: Uint8Array) => {
        console.log('write data: ', data);
        fdata.push(data);
    }, (m?: StreamMetadata) => {
        if (m) {
            metadata = m;
        }
    });

    if (!encodeInterleaved) {
        // separate interleaved data into channels
        const list: Int32Array[] = deinterleave(data, channels);
        flac.FLAC__stream_encoder_process(enc, list, data.length / channels);
    } else {
        flac.FLAC__stream_encoder_process_interleaved(enc, data, data.length / channels);
    }

    flac.FLAC__stream_encoder_finish(enc);
    flac.FLAC__stream_encoder_delete(enc);

    cb(fdata, metadata as unknown as StreamMetadata);
}

function deinterleave(data: Int32Array, channels: number): Int32Array[] {
    const len = data.length;
    const samples = len / channels;
    const list: Int32Array[] = new Array(channels).fill(null).map(() => new Int32Array(samples));
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i += channels) {
        for (var j = 0; j < channels; ++j) {
            list[j][i / channels] = data[i + j];
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

In the process I also had to **modify** my `next.config.json`, because of some problem with `webpack` had **loading static resources** from the package.

---

## Alternatives?

What **alternatives** are there to **encoding/decoding** the WAVs using `javascript`/`typescript`?

1. For example, is running a `FLAC` `bash` command on the server for every request even scalabale for a **realtime application with many users**?
2. Would a `C`, `C++` or `Python` **implementation** be better for this matter?